# Generate a gesture event in android

Tags: android, events, gesture

I want to generate a swipe right or left event in android, I don't want to capture them. I just want to simulate the event so someone could navigate from right to left without his finger. I can't find any documentation on that. I dont know if I search in the wrong place, but I need to know how this could be done. Any hint will be appreciated on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer my question, I think someone post it already but the answer is gone. So there it is : https://github.com/kritts/HandWave. Sorry for the delay for the person that had posted the answer before but I had to test it before.